# Not able to copy from EC2 in windows

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I am not able to copy log file from ec2 instance to my local machine (windows). Command that I am using

```
scp -i ~/Desktop/Repo/mypemfile.pem ec2-user@xyz.co:/logfilelocation/fileName.log ~/Documents/Test.log
```

Error that I am getting

```
~/Documents/Test.log: No such file or directory
```

Stuck in this pls help

Comment: Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code problems. Please delete your question here and repost to [su].  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be saying that `~/Documents/Test.log` is not a valid **directory** name.

I looked through the documentation and it seems that the **destination** needs to be a **path name** without the filename. So, try downloading with:

```
scp -i ~/Desktop/Repo/mypemfile.pem ec2-user@xyz.co:/logfilelocation/fileName.log ~/Documents/
```

You'll then need to rename the file locally.